# git commands not working in terminal

Tags: git, terminal

Git at terminal behaving very weirdly.

Here is how terminal responds when I have a git command

```
git log
```

[image]

Not sure how to fix it.

this is how .bash_profile loks like

```
"$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
if [ -f /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash ]; then
. /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/git-completion.bash
fi

export PS1='\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$(git branch     &>/dev/null; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "\[\033[01;33m\]($(git branch | grep ^*|sed s/\*\ //))\[\033[00m\]"; fi)$ '
```

Comment: Is this a problem with git or your color scheme?

Comment: I guess there is some problem with git, because I tried deleting the if and export statements in profile. It is behaving the same.

Comment: Could you try running `git log | less` and see if you see any valid output within the `less` pager ?

Comment: Or try "git log > /tmp/foo 2>&1" and then examine /tmp/foo in an editor. I doubt it's a color problem though, the output was too short, although perhaps the error messages were rendered unreadable. Note also, that "git log" pipes through less by default, unless you've changed your configs. Finally, what do you get if you "echo $?" after the "git log" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the git color configuration with the following command:

`git config --global color.ui [always|auto|never]`